# Visual C++ code not working in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, visual-studio, codeblocks

I have the following code that I am currently using to call functions from a C# Dll, which works perfectly in Visual C++.

```
#include <mscoree.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "mscoree.lib") 

void Bootstrap()
{
    ICLRRuntimeHost *pHost = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CorBindToRuntimeEx(L"v4.0.30319", L"wks", 0, CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost, IID_ICLRRuntimeHost, (PVOID*)&pHost);
    pHost->Start();
    printf("HRESULT:%x\n", hr);

    // target method MUST be static int method(string arg)
    DWORD dwRet = 0;
    hr = pHost->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(L"c:\\temp\\test.dll", L"Test.Hello", L"SayHello", L"Person!", &dwRet);
    printf("HRESULT:%x\n", hr);

    hr = pHost->Stop();
    printf("HRESULT:%x\n", hr);

    pHost->Release();
}

int main()
{
    Bootstrap();
}
```

The problem is, when I move this into Code::Blocks (which I am more familiar with - as the little C++ I have done has been native) throws a lot of compiler errors.

The original compiler errors were because it couldn't find the header `mscoree.h`. I found this in the .NET SDK, so I copied it over to the mingw include directory which solved that, and then I did the same for all the other headers it couldn't find.

After copying over all the headers it then started giving a whole load of other errors, to do with the code in the headers I had just moved - nothing to do with the code below.

Why is Code::Blocks having such a hard time running this when VS runs it straight off the bat?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some of the errors? Have you set up the project to link with `mscoree.dll`?

Comment: I will try and find them again, from memory it's `function not defined` errors in various headers. How do I link the project to `mscoree.dll`?

Comment: Function definitions not being found definitely sounds like a linker error. I'm haven't really ever used Code::Blocks personally, but perhaps this will help? http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/

Comment: I'd also recommend against copying SDK headers; add the directory they are in your Compiler Directories. The same thing about `mscoree.lib`.

Comment: @Yuushi Thanks Yuushi, I will check out that and see if it fixes it.

Comment: I think pragma(comment, "mscoree.lib") will only work in VS. It's the equivalent of linking to mscoree.lib in the project settings.

Comment: All `#pragma`s are compiler-dependent and generally non-portable. And yes, Skalli is right, it just tells the linker to link the according library.

Comment: The `#pragma`'s do seem to be flagging as an error. Is there anything else I can use instead of these in CB?

Comment: @BaliC: As mentioned, you can use the project settings to tell the linker what it should link...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Code::Blocks** is a great IDE for C++ programming, but you are clearly doing Windows programming here. Though it is the same programming language, compilers are not compatible among them.

Either if you have downloaded the CodeBlocks version with the gcc compiler, or the single CodeBlocks IDE, you need to configure CodeBlocks in order to use the MS C++ compiler. In order to do that, go to *Settings >> Compiler and debugger >> Toolchain executables*.

Also, in the same option, look for *Search directories* and place there the path to the MS C++ compiler headers.

Once that is done, you will be able to compile your program.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have switched to VS C++ compiler and added the directory into the include directories but after compiling I got 50 errors and 139 warnings. Any ideas?

Comment: Here you have an explanation of how to use Visual C 6 with CodeBlocks. The process is very similar. http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Integrating_Microsoft_Visual_C_6_with_Code::Blocks_IDE

Answer (score 0):

Code::Blocks has a different compiler altogether from Visual Studio, the decoding and encoding on source code during compilation is different and cannot recognize each other though they are same programming language.